# Pytest errors during collection interrupts program running

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Building a program that creates a (string) phone number object and manipulates it in a bunch of ways.

The test suite calls for a number of value errors. It has been very difficult to implement these and have the program pass those tests.

For instance, the call to number1.number below returns:

```
Interrupted: 1 errors during collection
```

The program then stops and doesn't call number2.

My question: How do I write the below code so that it continues on after throwing the first exception?

```
class Phone (object):

    def __init__(self, phone_number):
        punctuation = ['\'', '+', '(', ')', '-', '.',',',' ']
        self.clean_number = [item for item in phone_number if item not in punctuation]
        self.output = ''.join(self.clean_number)
        if self.clean_number[0] == '1' and len(self.clean_number) > 10:
                self.clean_number = self.clean_number[1:]
        self.verify()

    @property
    def number(self):
        if len(self.output) > 10:
            return self.output[1:]
        else:
            return self.output

    @property
    def area_code(self):
        return self.output[:3]

    def pretty(self):
        pretty_number = [char for char in self.clean_number]
        pretty_number.insert(0, '(')
        pretty_number.insert(4, ')')
        pretty_number.insert(5, ' ')
        pretty_number.insert(9, '-')
        return ''.join(pretty_number)

    def verify(self):
        if 'a' in self.clean_number:
            raise ValueError("Letter in number.")

number1 = Phone("123-abc-7890")
print(number1.number)

number2 = Phone("(213) 555-3456")
print(number2.number)
```

And here's the test, fwiw:

```
def test_invalid_with_letters(self):
    with self.assertRaisesWithMessage(ValueError):
        Phone("123-abc-7890")
```

Comment: Why not fix the errors, then? Interrupts during test collection show that your module raises an error on import and is thus unusable.

Comment: this is a value error to satisfy a unit test in a test suite. if the program doesn’t successfully throw the error, it doesn’t pass the test. the problem is that when it reads this value error it gives an error during test collection and shuts everything down. so it seems there is probably something wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Why do you raise a value error on module import, then? Your module is unusable in its current state. If you want to test `Phone("123-abc-7890")`, remove it from module code and put it in the test code - this is what you have already done in `test_invalid_with_letters`. What purpose do `number1` and `number2` serve?

Comment: This is an exercise for exercism.io, this is in the test suite and exercise won’t pass without being able to do this

Comment: You mean [this one](https://github.com/exercism/python/tree/master/exercises/phone-number)? No, it doesn't require having anything like `number1 = Phone("123-abc-7890")` on module level. The only thing required for the tests to pass is the `Phone` class to be implemented correctly. Remove everything besides the class to make the test suite run.

Answer (score 0):

This error arises when it is unable to get the imports which are defined for the test file. So to pick up the paths you should use the sys module to mention the path from where the files should be picked.

```
import sys    
sys.path.append('../project_name')  ## mention the path of the folder where the files need to be imported
```